# Composite Pattern Reuse For Different Types

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, composite

Extending a naval simulation project, I'm looking to add the Composite Pattern so I can have groups of objects.  This is what the current hierarchy looks like:

```
class Sim_object {
};

class Ship : public Sim_object {
};

class Island : public Sim_object {
};
```

And so far I've come up with:

```
class Sim_object {
  // holds general sim functions
  get_name()
};

// COMPONENT
class Ship_object : public Sim_object {
  // holds ship functions
  add()
  remove()
  attack()
  move()
};

// COMPOSITE
class Group : public Ship_object {
   // holds list of group ship functions
   add()
   remove()
   attack()
   move()
};

// LEAF
class Ship : public Ship_object {
   // holds ship functions
   attack()
   move()
};

class Island : public Sim_object {
  // holds island functions
};
```

I have it working, but it only works for Ships and groups of Ship.  I'd like to reuse the Group code (add, remove, display, etc.) so then a concrete Group class (like Island_group) can just inherit from this and use it.  I tried changing the design where Ship_group class inherits from a common base class called Group, but I was faced with a diamond program.

Is there any way I can go about reusing my Group control code based on the type?

Comment: This does not look like composite to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The composite, in order to work with more than one type of `Sim_object`, should inherit and compose `Sim_objects`:

```
class Sim_object { };
class Ship : public Sim_object { };
class Island : public Sim_object { }; 
class Group : public Sim_object { 
  add()
  remove()
};
```

To tailor it to specific types, you could templatize it, and (possibly) derive other groups from it:

```
template <class T>
class Group : public Sim_object {
  add()
  remove()
};

class Ship_Group : public Group<Ship> {
  attack()
  move()
};

class Island_Group : public Group<Island> { } // possibly unnecessary
```

Now, to have your `Ship_Group` substitute `Ship`s, you could create an "interface" (pure-virtual class) for `Ship` and inherit `Ship_Group` from it as well. You'd also use your new interface instead of the concrete `Ship` in client code:

```
class Ship_Like { // interface
  attack() = 0
  move() = 0
};
class Ship : public Sim_object, public Ship_Like { }; // concrete
class Ship_Group : public Group<Ship>, public Ship_Like { 
  attack()
  move()
}
```

No worries about diamond-problems there...

Comment: What type of objects does the container in Group class hold?  I understand it's templated, but when Ship_group derives from it using Group<Ship_like> I get errors because my container is trying to hold objects of an abstract class.

Comment: Well, it should have worked. Anyway, I changed it to `Group<Ship>`. Use `Group<Ship_Like>` if you want to have recursive composites (groups of groups ...). What error did you get? With what code?

Comment: Problem Im having is what classes account for which responsibilities.  In the composite pattern, the client should interface with one class to handle ships and groups of ships.  I got the Ship_like working; however now I'm not sure where to handle Add()/Remove().  I want to be able to retrieve a Ship_like object and then add or remove it through that.  Do I need to add an Add/Remove function to Ship_like?  I guess which part of the code does the client interface with when adding/removing ships.  Likewise, I need to be able to access Sim_object functions for parent, name, and location functions

Comment: Additionally I have get_object() functions so I can retrieve said object based on name.  My container in Group is a map of shared_ptrs.

Comment: `add/remove` should be part of the composite (`Group`). Code that adds or removes components must know it's dealing with a `Group`

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the composite pattern?  Shouldn't I be able to retrieve an object and add to it.  It will either throw an exception or add the component depending on if it's a leaf or composite.  I was under the impression the client did not need to know whether he's dealing with a composite or leaf.

Comment: Well, clients that use `add/remove` need to know about the composite, whereas clients that use `Ship_Like` behavior can be handled any "ship-like" class, including a composite, and should work regardless. So, there're at least 2 types of clients.