# Dynamic Cast or Second Container of Objects?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

I have a template class for a Group of objects that other more specialized groups can derive from (using this for Composite pattern).  Anyway, my Group class handles all of the actual group code.

Right now I have a single container holding objects of type T, but I also need to access another base class's interface by cross-casting.  Do you recommend I have a container for both interfaces or just dynamic_cast each object as I loop through the first container?

```
class Sim_object {
  add(Sim_object_sp_t object)
  remove(Sim_object_sp_t object)
};

class Group<T> : public class Sim_object {
  add(Sim_object_sp_t object)
  remove(Sim_object_sp_t object)
  map<T>
  protected iterators begin(), end() (for use by Ship_group to use for dock, attack, move functions)
  // looking to add map<Sim_object> to prevent casting from T to Sim_object in Add/Remove but still give derived classes access to map<T> iterators.
};

class IShip {
  dock() = 0
  attack() = 0
  move() = 0
};

class Ship_group : public Group<IShip>, public IShip {
  dock()  // uses iterators provided by Group to loop through and call dock()
  attack() // same as dock
  move() // same as dock
};

class Ship : public Sim_object, public IShip {
  dock()
  attack()
  move()
};
```

So the two interfaces I need access to in Group is T (IShip in this case) and Sim_object.

Example from Group:

```
template<typename T>
void Group<T>::add(Sim_object_sp_t object) { 
  if (object->get_parent())
    object->get_parent()->remove(object);

  std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> t_object = std::tr1::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(object);
  if (!t_object)
    throw Error("Failed to cast to type T");

  objects[object->get_name()] = t_object;
  object->set_parent(shared_from_this());
}
```

Example from Ship_group:

```
void Ship_group::set_destination_position_and_speed(Point destination_position, double speed) {
  for (Iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it) {
    try {
      it->second->set_destination_position_and_speed(destination_position, speed);
    } catch (const Error& e) {
      cout << it->second->get_name() << " -- " << e.msg << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will all uses of the `Group` class require `T` to have the desired interface?  If so, I'd think you can just program your `Group` template assuming that all `T`'s have the desired interface (no `dynamic_cast` required).  The template compiler will simply fail when instantiating the `Group` template class for any types `T` that fail to meet the criteria.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right response but right now I derive a Ship_group class from Group<IShip> where IShip is an abstract base class for all Ship-like objects.  So I do not really want to pollute T.  I also have a Sim_object class that Group inherits from and performs component functions as a part of the composite pattern.  I don't want to pollute either interface just so I can avoid a dynamic_cast.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could sketch out the skeleton code for the class hierarchy you've just described.  Can you add this to your question?

Comment: Can you explain why both `Group<T>` and `Sim_object` have `add()` and `remove()` functions?  The two classes seem unrelated.

Comment: They are used for the composite pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Now, I can represent groups of objects, and groups of groups of objects, etc...

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code where you need to use `dynamic_cast`?  Also, I'm curious why `Ship_group` is both an `IShip` and a group of `IShip`s (`Group<IShip>`).

Comment: Ship_group implements the interface of a Ship.  It will have recursive nature and depending on if it's a Ship_group or Ship, will call the respect IShip functions.

Comment: Here is an example of the pattern I'm using:
http://www.cumps.be/zip/image?path=/public/images/blog/composite/composite2.gif

Comment: Please note - in your example code - `void Group<T>::add(Sim_object_sp_t object)` is not defined in your class declaration - so the skeleton code doesn't seem complete.

Comment: It's just pseudocode, I will fix for better understanding.

Comment: It's critical for this question, because you're `dynamic_cast`ing an argument to a function that does not exist in the skeleton architecture you've provided, so the templatized type and the function argument appear to be doing double duty.

Comment: Is it deliberate that the code does not match the "Composite" pattern in the link you gave above?  `Ship_group` and `IShip` seem to correspond to the Composite pattern, but they do not actually derive from a base class that implements `dock()`, `attack()` and `move()`, and in addition, `Ship_group` should not derive from `IShip` (if `Ship_group` and `IShip` correspond to the Composite pattern).  Furthermore, `Sim_object` does not seem to be part of the Composite pattern in this example except that `Ship_group` and `IShip` could both derive from it, but they don't (& its interface isn't right).

Comment: Sim_object is component, Group is composite, and Ship is leaf or IShip is component, Ship_group is composite, and Ship is leaf.  A design pattern does not have to be exact, it can be modified to fit needs (which I have done).  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112359/composite-pattern-reuse-for-different-types

The goal of the composite pattern is for the client to interact with a common interface and not have to worry about leafs or composites(groups).  I have achieved this and have the code working.  I'm merely looking to refactor to improve maintainability, efficiency, and style.

Comment: Thanks - now the question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a nested type inside `class Group<T>`:

```
class Group<T> : public class Sim_object {
    class Specialized_Sim_Object : public T, public Sim_object {}
    void add(Specialized_Sim_Object * object) {
        objects[object->get_name()] = object;
    }
}
```

The `shared_ptr` may not be necessary in this case, either - when `Ship_group` iterates through the map, the type is already guaranteed to be an `IShip`.